# Jersy Rest service to accept java.util.Map for MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have written a Jersey rest service which accepts `java.util.Map` as input for example

```
@POST
@Path("validate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String validate(Map<String,String> data) throws Exception
```

And from UI post Response structure is:

```
{"data":{"abcd":"5210","two":"5173"}}
```

Server gives an issue

```
"SEVERE: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, type=class java.util.HashMap, genericType=java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>."
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: If you make a method that *returns* a Map, what does the JSON look like from that? I'd use that format, only in reverse, for this method.

Comment: I did the same thing

Comment: Jersey cannot interprete parameter names (afaik) like `data`. It can only use class names, field names and annotation values. You could try to create a container class, having a single instance field `Map<String,String> data`.

Comment: Which JSON provider are you using? Not entirely sure, but I believe Jackson could do it, but it may be problematic with Moxxy (which is now the default Json provider with Jersey 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to change that put the Map object in a wrapper class like

class MapWrapper {

private Map data;

}

and from Jersey Client send the JSON string of object of Map.